# Print twig variable inside function

Tags: drupal, twig

How do I output the variable target_id instead of node.nid? inside the function call?

`{% set  target_id = content.field_internal_lnk %}
<a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': node.nid }) }}">{{ content.field_button_text }}</a>`

Answer (score 2):

By using the right variable name?

```
{'node': target_id }
```

Comment: That's what I did. 
I solved the issue already. target_id was not the raw value.

Comment: path() expexted an integer. target_id value I passed was an array. That was the problem.